# Retrieve and Rank in Python-Configuration File Type?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I'm using the `retrieve_and_rank` class in Python from the `watson_developer_cloud` package.

**Main question:**

In the `create_config` function, what type of object do we pass in for the `config` argument? A zip folder?

I'm using IBM's provided example configuration folder just to test, and when I call

```
retriever_and_ranker.create_config(MY_ID, CONFIG_NAME, 'blank_example_solr_config.zip')
```

I get this error:

> WatsonException: unknown error

The zipped folder is in the same directory as my code. What should that last argument be? I'm wondering why it doesn't recognize the zip file from the string I'm passing in.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the key was that I was incorrectly passing in a string, as opposed to an open file object.

You need to use the

```
with open("file.zip", "rb) as fp:
    ...
```

as in joe's answer.